# Android download manager copy file from cache

Tags: android

How to copy a file downloaded by download manager in internal storage's cache folder. I am using fileInputStream, but it through's permison denied. Is there any option to copy file

Comment: Hi, if you find a way to doing this, please share it with me.

Answer (score 1):

it has been a while since the question was asked but anyway, I found the answer this morning:
You simply can't copy files from you Caches folder. What you can do is to create your file in another folder (Files folder for example, which you get by doing getFilesDir()) and delete it if necessary ! 
Hope it helps, 
Bye

Answer (score -1):

Set permission in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER" />
```